# composite index in mysql if one column is very frequent

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table which contains data for multiple tenants.

```
CREATE TABLE `accountPost` (
 `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tenantId` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
 `accountId` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `scheduledTime` BIGINT(19),
 ......more columns
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=781625 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Here, scheduledTime is the time stamp. tenantId will be common for lot of accountPost rows.

Now, I have a query like

```
select * from accountPost
    where scheduledTime > t1
      and scheduledTime < t2
      and tenantId = "x";
```

For this query, I want to create an composite index.

```
1. ALTER TABLE `accountPost` ADD INDEX `idx1` (`scheduledTime`, `tenantId`);
2. ALTER TABLE `accountPost` ADD INDEX `idx1` (`tenantId`, `scheduledTime`);
```

Which one out of these two should I use to get optimal performance for insert as well as read and why?
Should more frequent column be added as first in composite index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cardinality of individual components of a composite index is irrelevant.

What is vital is to put `=` columns before `<` (etc) columns.  So this is necessarily the better order:

```
INDEX(`tenantId`, `scheduledTime`)
```

(Meanwhile, the order of clauses in `WHERE` is not important.)

As for read vs write...  The `SELECT` benefit from a good index far outweighs the minor overhead for writing (insert/update/delete).  Add all the indexes needed for reads; toss any redundant or never-used indexes.  Then don't worry.

Tip on comparing dates (or datetimes):  Beware of `BETWEEN` or, in your example, `<` and `>` -- they either include or exclude *both* endpoints.  I like the following pattern:

```
WHERE dt >= '2019-12-27'
  AND dt  < '2019-12-27' + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Tip of schemas:  Think about using smaller datatypes.  `255` is handy, but has some minor performance issues.  `BIGINT` (8 bytes) is almost always bigger than necessary.  Size matters for disk space and caching.

Where did you get `BIGDECIMAL`??

More: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: `BIGDECIMAL` Was a typo. So, while writing, for both the performance would be same?

Comment: The order of the columns in an `INDEX` is very important for performance in your query.  (It does not matter when all the columns are being tested with `=`.)

Comment: will all the writes for a particular tenantId will be sequential for index (tenantId, scheduledTime) ?

Comment: @sabu - The performance impact on the writes is less important than the benefit on the reads.  Anyway, how many different `tenantIds` are there?  Are the writes in `scheduledTime` order?

Comment: I am expecting maximum 3-4, usually it will be 1 or 2. No `scheduledTime` writes are not in order.

Comment: @sabu - Then the answer is "no" to "the writes for a particular tenantId will be sequential for index (tenantId, scheduledTime)".  What did you mean by the question?

Comment: sequential means "if I need to save multiple entries for the same tenant at the same time, it will be done one after another." because of `tenantId` index will block the concurrent inserts as one insert updates the B tree .